# How to omit sublayout from row in androidlist through SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListFragment`, where each row is formed by several data retrieved from the database. This data is structured in sub-layouts, and one of them consist of a `LinerLayout` with a fixed text and a dynamic text to be populated from the db, something like `Value: X` where X is the value coming from the database.

However that value is optional in the db, and in case the value is not present, I would like not to present the fixed text.

The question was how to do that in the `SimpleCursorAdapter` responsible for the layout inflate of the rows.

Here is the layout of the rows, where the sub-layout composed by the fixed and dynamic texts is the one with the id **valueLayout**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >

        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alert"
                android:text="Alert"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:text="Desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/valueLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/valueFixedText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Value: "
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="date"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I could not find the answer directly here in SO and had to hunt down some pieces of information. Therefore, I decided to share the answer here as well

Answer (score 0):

The solution basically consisted on overwriting the `bindView` method from the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, checking for the value in the cursor, and if it was not present, get the sub-layout and set its visibility to `View.GONE`

```java
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        super.bindView(v, context, c);
        // the value is empty, we clear its linear layout
        String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DATA.VALUE));
        if(null == value || value.isEmpty()){           
            LinearLayout valueLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.valueLayout);
            valueLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }   
}
```